# Adobe Acrobat signature field does not make other fields “read only” when signed on android

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

We are using adobe acrobat pro, and creating a simple form that a user can sign on an android tablet. The problem is that when the users sign the document, the fields do not become "read only". If I open the documents on my desktop, I can edit all the fields except the signature field, even if it was signed by another user.

I'm sure it's some silly setting issue, but we've already used the document security settings and adjusted the digital signature form field settings to "make all fields read only" and "locked" the signature field.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Any third-party PDF reader will do the same. If you're intending to rely on these "signatures" as some kind of proof of acceptance, you're setting yourself up for legal trouble later.

Comment: We aren't using any third-party software. Just adobe reader and adobe acrobat?

Comment: I understood that. I'm just warning you that you can't rely on the fields being read-only on other platforms either. A signature field in a PDF file is not a replacement for a cryptographic digital signature. Maybe you already knew this, but since the potential consequences are quite big, I thought I'd better warn you in case.